# std::extent implementation details explanation

Tags: c++, templates

```
// basic template: covers non-array types
template<class T, unsigned N = 0>
struct extent : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

// 1st specialization: covers 1st dimension of array of uknown bound
template<class T>
struct extent<T[], 0> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

// 2nd specialization: covers Nth dimension of array of uknown bound
template<class T, unsigned N>
struct extent<T[], N> : extent<T, N-1> {};

// 3rd  specialization: covers 1st dimension of array of known type
template<class T, std::size_t I>
struct extent<T[I], 0> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {};

// 4th  specialization: covers Nth dimension of array of known type
template<class T, std::size_t I, unsigned N>
struct extent<T[I], N> : extent<T, N-1> {};
```

Possible implementation taken from other resource.
Could respectable community please explain me how this works. Looking to the 4th spec it's unclear how `<T[I]>`, that's recursively passed to base class as `<T, N - 1>`, is transforming to sub-array type of array of upper level of inheritance. For example if we call `extent< int[2][5], 1 >` where `T[I] = int [2][5], N = 1` then we pass to base class `T, N - 1;` base is instantiating as if we pass `int[2]` because very first (most derrived) `T[I]` is considered as array of two `int[5]`, so `T` in base class is `int[5]` where `I = 5`. Is this correct?

Next, why 2nd spec (for array of uknown bound) instead of using zero size, as 1st spec, is relying on recursive instantiation as if on some level size of the dimension could be known. What's context of this case, could you please provide an example?

runnable snippet:
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2150f81a547674e6

Side: someone pointed out the https://cppinsights.io/ which helpful; also there's Microsoft's C++ build insights (doesn't work for me).

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: you are right.

`extent<int[2][5], 1>` uses 4th specialization, resulting in

```
template<class T=int[5], std::size_t I=2, unsigned N=1>
struct extent<T[I], N> : extent<int[5], 0> {};
```

That uses 3rd specialization, resulting in

```
template<class T=int, std::size_t I=5>
struct extent<T[I], 0> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 5> {};
```

So `extent<int[2][5], 1>::value` is `5`.

Regarding question 2 let's take `extent<int[][5], 1>` as an example. It uses specialization 2 and results in

```
template<class T=int[5], unsigned N=1>
struct extent<T[], N> : extent<int[5], 0> {};
```

That uses the 3rd specialization, not the first!

```
template<class T=int, std::size_t I=5>
struct extent<T[I], 0> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 5> {};
```

In my opinion the 1st overload is not necessary. Visual Studio 2019's STL omits this one and just falls back to the basic template.

As I previously wrote in a comment you can also fiddle around on https://cppinsights.io/.